# Grassmannian manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, grassmannian, complex-manifolds

How can I prove that the Grassmannian manifold $Gr(k,n)$ is a holomorphic manifold? For example I'd like to prove it for $Gr(2,4)$. How can I do it finding charts and proving that changes of chartes are holomorphic?

Comment: One way to do this is to use affine coordinates. See here: http://books.google.ca/books?id=_XxZdhbtf1sC&pg=PA66&lpg=PA66&dq=affine+coordinates+grassmannian&source=bl&ots=3m6lHfpIkz&sig=_FNuzAw73D8r1MaedBCTmqE7Ycc&hl=fr#v=onepage&q=affine%20coordinates%20grassmannian&f=false

Comment: @julien Is there a more elegant way? Using Segre map...?

Comment: How did you prove that it id a manifold? (Or an affine variety)? If the transition functions you had are not regular functions I would be very surprised! (I gaave an atlas [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225673/intrinsic-proof-that-the-grassmannian-is-a-manifold/225711#225711) by the way)

Comment: I have to prove that it is a manifold... so I have to find the charts and show that changes of charts are olomorphic.

Comment: @ArthurStuart Of course, it is a matter of personal taste, but I find the affine coordinates fairly elegant.

Comment: But when I find affine coordinates I have to prove that the changes of coordinates are holomorphic...

Comment: Have you worked out the changes of coordinates?  I'd expect them to be rational functions, so they'll be holomorphic wherever the denominators don't vanish.  (And where the denominators *do* vanish will be outside the relevant charts.)